# scapy. adding urgent data to TCP packet

Tags: python, tcp, scapy

I am trying to add single byte 0x00 as 'urgent' data to TCP packet.
If i understand correctly all I need to to is set `URG` flag in packet ,

and  change urgent pointer to 1.

If i am mistaken, please, explain where and why.

So if i have `packet = IP()/TCP()`

```
packet.flags=0x8
```

(set URG flag)

```
packet.urgptr=1
```

(set urgent pointer)

```
packet.payload.payload = 0x00
```

(add data)

Is this all i need or i missing something?

Many thanks!

Comment: Did you try it?  What happened?

Comment: I did. Packet is correct, but i am not sure how to test it.

Comment: Run netcat or some other program to be the other end of the connection, and inspect the flow using wireshark/tcpdump/etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
packet.flags = 0x8
```

will set the flags option in the IP header, and not the TCP header.You need to do

```
packet.getlayer(TCP).flags = 32 # or 0x20
```

to set the URG flag of the TCP header.

As for testing this, I am assuming packet.show() is not enough? What do you need this "urgent" packet to do?